# NPM - Excluding a part of dependency from installing

Tags: git, npm, npmignore

I have a problem, which come from the thing that I replace a bootstrap.min.css with another one. I adjusted .gitignore in way, that on github repo there is only /node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css from all the dependencies. But after cloning the repo and use "npm i", this file is overrided. So I just want to add this specified file to .npmignore. But I don't have a idea how to do that. Could anybody want to reveal me the secret? :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't be doing it this way - it is not a supported scenario. What you need to do is put your modifications in another CSS file and put that in your main projects folder. This would overwrite the bootstrap.min.css. In the absolute worst case scenario, copy the bootstrap.min.css to your project and dont reference the node modules one.

Comment: Ok, I could go that way. But is there any possibility to do, what I intended firstly?

Comment: For clarity I use the theme from https://bootswatch.com/ and they're recommening to replace the orginal file ;x

Comment: By "replace the original file" I am sure in the context of npm they mean do not reference the node module, and reference your own file in code. This is standard practice.

As for the possibility of this, no I do not believe it is possible unless you want to do something silly like revoke write permissions from the npm process. You could however pull the source code for the npm module for bootstrap, make your changes and publish to a private NPM registry. This is for advanced users though and not worth the time.

Comment: Ok. But if I replace my src/styles.css with the bootswatch theme (for bootstrap v3), the transpilation will crash :/. So to prevent that I must to change my code and upgrade to bootstrap v4 or correct the source code of the theme.

Comment: Copy the bootstrap style to a new file "src/bootstrap.min.css" and reference this in your html before your "src/style.css". I cannot provide further help in the comment section  -extended conversations are for [SO Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com).